# Add new key/pair to object when two values, from two diff objects match

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have mapped and filtered two objects. I've hit a wall in my thinking. I cannot see how to add the key/value from one object to the other when the values match.

This type of sort is fairly new to me and wearing my logic thinking out, so any help will be appreciated.

I want to add the 'lat' and 'lon' values, with keys from the 'todaysDataPostcode' object, to the 'data' object.

This should be done when the postcodes match.

I'm using an approach I have done before, but the final stage is different and it's proving difficult to figure out

here's the code:

```
addLatLon = (location, latLon) => {
        return location.map(compiledDataObj => {
            const objectsWithSameLocation = latLon.filter(dataObj => {
                return dataObj.postcode === compiledDataObj.postcode;
            });

            objectsWithSameLocation.map(obj => {
                //here we want to match the postcode of the object we're running through
                // so its like
            compiledDataObj.postcode[obj.postcode]

                // return console.log('location.postcode', location.map(i => i.postcode), 'obj.postcode', obj.postcode)
            });
        });
    };
```

Here are the 2 datasets. The first one is only a partial version as this will be sufficient to implement logic.

Below is: 'data'

```
[
    {
        "location": "City of London",
        "postcode": "EC1A 7BE",
        "year": {
            "10": "464436",
            "11": "442413",
            "12": "525723",
            "13": "465451",
            "14": "625001",
            "15": "783667",
            "16": "736788",
            "17": "820305",
            "18": "802129",
            "19": "864034",
            "95": "91449",
            "96": "108999",
            "97": "116343",
            "98": "124382",
            "99": "149143",
            "00": "173738",
            "01": "284262",
            "02": "344239",
            "03": "261645",
            "04": "326913",
            "05": "330363",
            "06": "316121",
            "07": "360923",
            "08": "471861",
            "09": "400317"
        }
    },
    {
        "location": "Barking & Dagenham",
        "postcode": "RM9 4TP",
        "year": {
            "10": "162905",
            "11": "163821",
            "12": "163899",
            "13": "167919",
            "14": "184884",
            "15": "220070",
            "16": "258758",
            "17": "282441",
            "18": "291548",
            "19": "298333",
            "95": "50460",
            "96": "50828",
            "97": "54459",
            "98": "57559",
            "99": "64532",
            "00": "71079",
            "01": "82343",
            "02": "98713",
            "03": "134750",
            "04": "150115",
            "05": "164484",
            "06": "162340",
            "07": "176577",
            "08": "194235",
            "09": "166798"
        }
    }]
```

Here is the second data set: 'todaysDataPostcode'

```
 [{
        "postcode": "EC1A 7BE",
        "longitude": -0.100404,
        "latitude": 51.51775
    },
    {
        "postcode": "RM9 4TP",
        "longitude": 0.127884,
        "latitude": 51.539774
    },
    {
        "postcode": "EN5 5RP",
        "longitude": -0.194074,
        "latitude": 51.65044
    },
    {
        "postcode": "DA16 3DN",
        "longitude": 0.102535,
        "latitude": 51.464737
    },
    {
        "postcode": "HA9 9AA",
        "longitude": -0.279243,
        "latitude": 51.563322
    },
    {
        "postcode": "BR1 3NN",
        "longitude": 0.017131,
        "latitude": 51.40827
    },
    {
        "postcode": "NW1 8QL",
        "longitude": -0.142696,
        "latitude": 51.53929
    },
    {
        "postcode": "CR2 7PA",
        "longitude": -0.094105,
        "latitude": 51.36292
    }]
```

i want to add the

As mentioned above this is the expected result, I can't hit the result and i am lost right now.

"I want to add the 'lat' and 'lon' values, with keys from the 'todaysDataPostcode' object, to the 'data' object.

This should be done when the postcodes match."

Comment: Lodash can help you search by key https://lodash.com/docs/2.4.2#findKey

Comment: Isn't there an argument against '_lodash'? The performance of my app would suffer, no? Also, i won't necessarily learn how this all works and get my head around the logic (n00b if my question didn't highlight this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you've been after?

```js
const arr1 = [{"location":"City of London","postcode":"EC1A 7BE","year":{"10":"464436","11":"442413","12":"525723","13":"465451","14":"625001","15":"783667","16":"736788","17":"820305","18":"802129","19":"864034","95":"91449","96":"108999","97":"116343","98":"124382","99":"149143","00":"173738","01":"284262","02":"344239","03":"261645","04":"326913","05":"330363","06":"316121","07":"360923","08":"471861","09":"400317"}},{"location":"Barking & Dagenham","postcode":"RM9 4TP","year":{"10":"162905","11":"163821","12":"163899","13":"167919","14":"184884","15":"220070","16":"258758","17":"282441","18":"291548","19":"298333","95":"50460","96":"50828","97":"54459","98":"57559","99":"64532","00":"71079","01":"82343","02":"98713","03":"134750","04":"150115","05":"164484","06":"162340","07":"176577","08":"194235","09":"166798"}}];

const arr2 = [{"postcode":"EC1A 7BE","longitude":-0.100404,"latitude":51.51775},{"postcode":"RM9 4TP","longitude":0.127884,"latitude":51.539774},{"postcode":"EN5 5RP","longitude":-0.194074,"latitude":51.65044},{"postcode":"DA16 3DN","longitude":0.102535,"latitude":51.464737},{"postcode":"HA9 9AA","longitude":-0.279243,"latitude":51.563322},{"postcode":"BR1 3NN","longitude":0.017131,"latitude":51.40827},{"postcode":"NW1 8QL","longitude":-0.142696,"latitude":51.53929},{"postcode":"CR2 7PA","longitude":-0.094105,"latitude":51.36292}];

const merged = arr1.map(e => (coords = arr2.find(ee => ee.postcode == e.postcode), Object.assign(e,{longitude:coords['longitude'],latitude:coords['latitude']})));

console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{ min-height: 100% }
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, I tried your solution and it has worked. Lat piece of the puzzle now patched :)